# Rules for pluralizing countable and non-countable quantities?

Tags: pluriel, accord, nombres

In English, by convention, nouns have singular and plural cases, but they don't really apply in a sensible way, for example zero is treated as plural, and measured quantities, even if they consist of one unit, are also treated as plural. A simpler interpretation is to treat the plural case as the default, with a special case for singular countable.

- 0 books -- non-singular countable
- 1 book -- singular countable
- 2 books -- non-singular countable

but:

- 0.0 litres -- measured (therefore non-countable) quantity
- 1.0 litres -- as above
- 2.0 litres -- as above

Does French have the same convention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En français, 0 est toujours singulier. En usage formel, tous les nombres strictement inférieurs à 2 (en valeur absolue) sont singuliers (voir : [Académie française — Nombres inférieurs à 2 : accord](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#57_strong-em-nombres-criture-lecture-accord-em-strong)). On trouve cependant quelquefois le pluriel pour les nombres compris entre 1 et 2.

> zéro litre
>   zéro virgule trois litre
>   un litre
>   un virgule trois litre (*moins formel* : un virgule trois litres)
>   deux litres

On dit souvent l'unité avant la virgule, auquel cas c'est toujours la seule partie entière qui compte. De plus, on peut omettre le mot « virgule » dans ce cas.

> zéro litre virgule trois *ou* zéro litre trois
>   un litre virgule trois *ou* un litre trois (*jamais* <s>un litres (virgule) trois</s>)

---

The rules are different in French and in English. Zero is always singular. In formal usage, the integer part is all that matters: any number that is less than 2 is singular (see: [Académie française — Nombres inférieurs à 2 : accord](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#57_strong-em-nombres-criture-lecture-accord-em-strong)); however you'll sometimes find the plural for numbers between 1 and 2.

> zéro litre
>   zéro virgule trois litre
>   un litre
>   un virgule trois litre (*moins formel* : un virgule trois litres)
>   deux litres

Often the unit is placed before the comma, in which case it's always the integer part that matters. In this case, “*virgule*” (decimal point) can be omitted.

> zéro litre virgule trois *ou* zéro litre trois
>   un litre virgule trois *ou* un litre trois (*jamais* <s>un litres (virgule) trois</s>)

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer and link to reference, much appreciated.